# Making my server virtual - what happens to my LVMs?

Tags: server, virtualization, lvm

I have a physical server with about 10TB in two different LVMs and VGs. I'm going to be installing a bare-metal hypervisor on the hardware now, which means I'll have to rebuild my Ubuntu server. I set up my LVMs a while ago but as far as I know they are all software constructs right? Is there a way I can backup my entire configuration and restore it on another virtual server?

Answer (score 2):

Volume information is stored on the disks, so it should be no problem as long as you can attach your physical volumes directly to the new virtual machine. The procedure would be no different than if you moved the disks into a new computer.

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/recipemovevgtonewsys.html

---

13.6. Moving a volume group to another system

It is quite easy to move a whole volume group to another system if, for example, a user department acquires a new server. To do this we use the vgexport and vgimport commands.

Note

vgexport/vgimport is not necessary to move drives from one system to another. It is an administrative policy tool to prevent access to volumes in the time it takes to move them.

13.6.1. Unmount the file system

First, make sure that no users are accessing files on the active volume, then unmount it

```
# unmount /mnt/design/users
```

13.6.2. Mark the volume group inactive

Marking the volume group inactive removes it from the kernel and prevents any further activity on it.

```
# vgchange -an design
vgchange -- volume group "design" successfully deactivated
```

13.6.3. Export the volume group

It is now necessary to export the volume group. This prevents it from being accessed on the ``old'' host system and prepares it to be removed.

```
# vgexport design
vgexport -- volume group "design" successfully exported
```

When the machine is next shut down, the disk can be unplugged and then connected to it's new machine

13.6.4. Import the volume group

When plugged into the new system it becomes /dev/sdb so an initial pvscan shows:

```
# pvscan
pvscan -- reading all physical volumes (this may take a while...)
pvscan -- inactive PV "/dev/sdb1"  is in EXPORTED VG "design" [996 MB / 996 MB free]
pvscan -- inactive PV "/dev/sdb2"  is in EXPORTED VG "design" [996 MB / 244 MB free]
pvscan -- total: 2 [1.95 GB] / in use: 2 [1.95 GB] / in no VG: 0 [0]
```

We can now import the volume group (which also activates it) and mount the file system.

If you are importing on an LVM 2 system, run:

```
# vgimport design
  Volume group "design" successfully imported
```

If you are importing on an LVM 1 system, add the PVs that need to be imported:

```
# vgimport design /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdb2
vgimport -- doing automatic backup of volume group "design"
vgimport -- volume group "design" successfully imported and activated
```

13.6.5. Activate the volume group

You must activate the volume group before you can access it.

```
# vgchange -ay design
```

13.6.6. Mount the file system

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/design/users
# mount /dev/design/users /mnt/design/users
```

The file system is now available for use.

Answer (score 0):

What are you planning on having xen and the dom0 boot from?  If you have another disk for that purpose, then you can just pass the existing disks directly through to the new vm and they will work without modification; you just have to set up an hvm domU.

A more typical setup would be to have the dom0 manage the disks using lvm and/or md for raid, then present the logical volumes to the guest vms as xen virtual disks.  The guest can stack its own lvm on top of the virtual disk if it wants to, but doesn't need to.  If it does, you just need to make sure that dom0 isn't trying to activate any volume groups it finds inside of its logical volumes, which may require modifying /etc/lvm/lvm.conf's filter rules.

Moving from the current system to such a setup via backup and restore just means you go through your usual disaster recovery routine: update your backup ( i.e. with `tar` ), boot the new vm, format the virtual drive ( which may involve setting up lvm again if you want to go that route ), then restore.